# MySQL SELECT FROM table a JOIN b WHERE not exists or expired

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, in this example called table `a` and table `b`. Now I want to select everything from table `a` if it does not has a match in table `b`, or the record in table `b` is expired.

I was thinking of using a `LEFT JOIN` on table `b` AND `b.key IS NULL`. That will give me all the records from table `a` and do not match table `a`.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

But I'm struggling with the expired part (3 days old is expired). I tried to put in the JOIN part like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

But this gives me the not expired items ant not the expired ones.

The next issue is, table b will have multiple matches. Meaning it can old a_id multiple times, but all with different timestamps. In the query for the expired record, I'm only interested in the latest record of table `b`.

#### Expected result

```
Product 3
```

**Table a**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Table b**

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**data**

```
INSERT INTO `a` (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Product 1'),
    (2, 'Product 2'),
    (3, 'Product 3');
INSERT INTO `b` (`id`, `a_id`, `created_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-08-20 12:30:32'),
    (2, 2, '2017-08-24 12:30:39');
    (3, 1, '2017-08-24 13:19:13');
```

Comment: Based upon the data set provided, what should the desired result look like?

Comment: `SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM a
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.id=b.a_id) OR 
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.id=b.a_id AND b.created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM a
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.id=b.a_id) OR (
(SELECT b.created_at FROM b WHERE a.id=b.a_id 
 ORDER BY b.created_at DESC LIMIT 1) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

Comment: This is almost wat I want, but this doesn't check if b has multiple matches to a. I updated my question data and added the expected result.

Comment: @Timo002 I tested my query in your environment, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> b.created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
>
> But this gives me the not expired items ant not the expired ones.

erm, really, this has you stumped?

```
b.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

> I'm only interested in the latest record of table  b

Then replace b with:

```
(SELECT base.* FROM b base
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM b prev
    WHERE prev.a_id=base.a_id
    AND prev.created_at>base.created_at
 )
) c
```

The performance will not be optimal (and there are at least 3 other ways to write the query) but without knowing what the schema looks like nor the data distribution, I can't tell you what would be the best solution.

Answer (score -2):

use 
LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN
This can give you results on a table b even if is null

Comment: They both are same.